# Can I install Ruby v1.8.7 in System(not in rvm) after installing ruby in RVM 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rvm, chef-infra, ruby-1.8

Actually, I have to work on Chef which use `system default ruby v 1.8.7`.
and with rvm installed ruby my Chef is not wroking. 
So , To make my chef server installation. I required to have ruby1.8.7 into my system.Before I was using ruby 1.9.3 for my project(via RVM).

Can anybuddy tell , How can I install Ruby v1.8.7  in System(not in rvm) after installing ruby in RVM 1.9.3 .

Or is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

you want to set a default ruby:

```
rvm use 1.8.7 --install --default
```

This will install ruby `1.8.7` if not installed, it will use it and set as default, so any time rvm is loaded - you will have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible but to be honest you are better with RVM, in this way you can have control over your machine

Answer (score 0):

`rvm use system` tells rvm to leverage a system install of Ruby. To set system Ruby as default, type `rvm reset`.

Comment: well, I want to install ruby into system. There is no ruby yet in system. ruby 1.9.3 is in rvm. and tells me `ruby already install at newest verison` :(

Comment: @ManishShrivastava you can completely remove the RVM install with `rvm implode`

Answer (score 0):

Use the package manager of your distribution, that's what `rvm system` is about - giving control back to your system.